# Error occurs when running node.js with mangoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to run my node.js with the native mangoDB driver. MangoDB is installed globally in my Mac. I have a folder under my root (/data/db) and in my project folder, I also have mangoDB inside the node_modules folder.

However, when I run app.js using console I still get an error message:

I check the mangoDB version using command "npm mangodb --version", and it returns "6.4.1", I assume it means I installed it properly?

```
`Internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:583
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'mongodb'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/*****/Desktop/FruitProject/app.js:3:21)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)`
```

Is there anything that I missed when I installed mangoDB or how can I fix it to make it work? Thank you!

Comment: It's __mongodb__, not mango.

Comment: well mangodb is an empty module https://www.npmjs.com/package/mangodb .
quite funny the module has 40 weekly downloads.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can use mongodb inside your node app correctly after installing it.

```
const mongodb = require('mongodb');
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/database_name';
MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } 
    else {
        var collection = db.collection('collection_name');
        "any query here"
    } 
    })
```

To solve your error you can try `npm install` in main folder or try reinstalling nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have installed [mangodb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mangodb-client), but you are using [mongodb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb) in your program.
That's why it throws Error: Cannot find module 'mongodb'

You can use [mongodb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb) native driver package or [mongoose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose) package to interact with mongodb on nodejs platform.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have not installed `mongodb`, and instead installed `mangodb`.  Both these are two different node modules.  Do a `npm i mongodb --save` to install `mongodb`.